# need help about SVM in Python and Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am beginner in machine learning and Python. I am trying to implement SVM into my data comparing between MATLAB and Python. I expect to get similar result, but I don't. I've tried to find out similar problem with mine, but not any or I miss them.

I have one set of training and test set which is binary classification.
Firstly, I did an implementation in MATLAB using built-in function svmtrain and svmclassify.

```
load('sample.mat')
y_test = y_test';
y_train = y_train';
%% Training and Classification 
svmStruct = svmtrain(X_train, y_train, 'boxconstraint', 0.1);
species = svmclassify(svmStruct, X_test);
%% Compute Accuracy
count = 0;
for i=1:length(X_test)
if species(i)==y_test(i)
    count = count+1;
end
end
count/length(X_test)*100
%% Plotting
scatter(time, X_test, [], species)
hold on 
y_test(y_test==1) = 0.03;
y_test(y_test==0) = -0.03;
plot(time, y_test, 'g')
```

Here is the result of test set (class A classified by red, Class B classified by blue, green line is the actual label of class A
[image]

Secondly, I did the same thing in Python using scikit-learning package.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.io as sio

from sklearn import svm

""" Load Data"""
LoadData = sio.loadmat('sample.mat')
X_test = LoadData['X_test'].reshape(-1, 1)
X_train = LoadData['X_train'].reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = LoadData['y_test'].T
y_train = LoadData['y_train'].T
time = LoadData['time']

""" Train Classifier """
clf = svm.LinearSVC(C=1.0)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

predict_X_test = clf.predict(X_test)    # Predict test set
acc = clf.score(X_test, y_test)         # Accuracy

""" Plotting """
plt.figure(1)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
plt.scatter(time, X_test, c = predict_X_test)
y_test[y_test==1] = 0.03
y_test[y_test==0] = -0.03
plt.plot(time, y_test)

""" Plot Threshold """
w = clf.coef_
b = clf.intercept_ 
xx = np.linspace(300,610)
yy = -b/w*np.ones(xx.shape)
yy = yy.T
plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')
```

Here is the result in Python. black line is its threshold. red line is the actual label of class A
[image]

By using Python, it seems like threshold is too high, even I tried to adjust C parameter, but it doesn't work at all.

I am right now having no idea what wrong in my code. Any suggestion is appreciated

**EDIT**

Here I did validation curve in the link below. I think I did it correctly.
[image]

Blue line is the curve from Python. Red line is from MATLAB. x axis is C parameter at [0.001 0.01 0.1 1 10 100] (I used log(x)), y axis is accuracy.

Comment: It would be interesting to see validation curves for matlab and python with varying parameter C

Comment: @Moritz I updated cross-validation. No any change in SVM using Python.

Comment: Try using Grid Search In Python to optimize some parameter, does it make sense? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html

Comment: When I see the red line, my first thought is that you would want to extend it further to the left and see whether it touches the blue line. (Perhaps at -10? or -100?)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin x axis is C parameter in log scale which are [0.001 0.01 0.1 1 10 100]. I extended the value to the left but accuracy decreases.

Comment: @Masoud Thanks. It is little confused, but I will try.

Comment: It seems to work now, maybe.
I adjusted  "clf = svm.LinearSVC(C = 0.10,  class_weight='auto')"
Then I need to understand how does "class_weight" work

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Your classes are inbalanced. Matlab seems to scale the data aper default but sklearn not. Look at `http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html` unbalanced problems